# Are some brands of shower valves compatible with others?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I just finished all of our shower tile work in our new basement bathroom. Upon doing so, the wife informed me she would like to change the color scheme *eyeroll*.

We have our shower valve already installed. While I did install a 12"x12" access panel behind the valve, I'd rather not have to use that. We currently have an American Standard valve installed. It's near impossible to find an American Standard trim kit in matte black.

My question is, are there certain brands that are compatible with others? I picked up another entire "Tuscany" tub/shower combo not thinking it wouldn't be compatible. What gives? Any advice? TIA!

Comment: Hmm it doesn't answer your question, but you could send the parts to be stripped and professionally powder coated.

Comment: Spray paint would be my suggestion, but powder coating would probably last longer (and be more expensive, thus more likely to convince the wife that what you've got it fine).

Comment: There are even plenty of DIY powder coating kits to be had. That said, matte black will look perpetually scuzzy in a shower. Aged bronze is one thing. Black is another.

Comment: This isn't a very specific question. The only answers can really be "yes" or "no". You're not going to get a compiled list of interchangeable systems. If you are looking for a particular replacement for your particular faucet, the question is off-topic as shopping assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I have sort of done this with an American Standard shower valve. There's three parts that need to be adapted. The trim ring is the easiest. Get a piece of aluminum plate, 1/8" is a good size and cut a circle large enough so it fits over the shower valve. Cut the outside so it fits in the hole in the wall. Match it up with the correct plate for the valve and mark it where the mounting screws are. Drill holes in that location just large enough so the mounting screws will go through. Now get the right length/thread screws and mount this plate to the valve. Now take your new trim ring and line it up and and mark where the screws hit the plate you fabricated. Drill and tap the plate you fabricated for the mounting screws for the new trim ring. Your new trim ring will fasten to this mounting plate.
As far as the trim tube that can be held in place by the trim ring. You should be able to silicone the trim tube to the trim ring which should hold it.
As far as the handle that's where you'll probably have some trouble. You'll need to go online and look at installation instructions to see if there's any that have the same mounting method, my guess is you'll strike out on this part.
Easiest thing to do is to look for a universal black shower trim kit. It should come with all the adapters.

Answer (score 0):

I would say generally no. The different brands exterior trim are meant to work with specific valves and even types of valves. Why not call American Standard and ask if they make/made exterior trim in the color your wife desires? Time spent on their web site might lead you directly to this answer. The hard part is identifying your valve or shower kit. If recently purchased, hopefully your receipt or the box provides the name of the shower valve kit. If older, then you'll have to do some hunting but I've found A.S. to be very helpful.
Second worst case scenario would be electroplating (?) the metal to another finish. Here in Seattle I know of at least 2 such businesses.
Worst case scenario is changing the valve and exterior trim.

I offer the above based on 13 years in plumbing supply helping customers identify their valves. That is why I advise keeping the box it comes in. That info will be handy if future repairs are needed.